# Error building the ONNX library from scratch Ubuntu 22.04.2

Tags: python, linux, pip, onnx

I'm trying to build the ONNX library from source going step by step according to [the official manual](https://github.com/onnx/onnx/tree/main). When I reach the final step of executing the `pip install -e .` command, I encounter some errors. As I understand, the library has been built, but something is still wrong. There were other errors that I was able to resolve by installing additional packages and dependencies, but for this one I cannot figure out what's wrong.
Here's the error output I've got:

```
Using pip 22.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.10)
Obtaining file:///home/curiouspan/studyingC/intel_test/onnx
  Running command pip subprocess to install build dependencies
  Collecting setuptools>=61
    Using cached setuptools-69.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (819 kB)
  Collecting protobuf>=3.20.2
    Using cached protobuf-4.25.1-cp37-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (294 kB)
  Installing collected packages: setuptools, protobuf
  Successfully installed protobuf-4.25.1 setuptools-69.0.2
  WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Running command Checking if build backend supports build_editable
  Checking if build backend supports build_editable ... done
  Running command Getting requirements to build wheel
  running egg_info
  writing manifest file 'UNKNOWN.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Running command pip subprocess to install backend dependencies
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.42.0-py3-none-any.whl (65 kB)
  Installing collected packages: wheel
  Successfully installed wheel-0.42.0
  WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Running command Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml)
  running dist_info
  creating /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-7id_y34f/UNKNOWN.egg-info
  writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-7id_y34f/UNKNOWN.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-7id_y34f/UNKNOWN.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Installing collected packages: UNKNOWN
  Running setup.py develop for UNKNOWN
    Running command python setup.py develop
    running develop
    /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py:158: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      warnings.warn(
    /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      warnings.warn(
    /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:116: PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning: 1.1build1 is an invalid version and will not be supported in a future release
      warnings.warn(
    running egg_info
    writing manifest file 'UNKNOWN.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    running cmake_build
    -- ONNX_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/protoc
    -- Protobuf_VERSION: 3.21.12
    Generated: /home/curiouspan/studyingC/intel_test/onnx/.setuptools-cmake-build/onnx/onnx-ml.proto
    Generated: /home/curiouspan/studyingC/intel_test/onnx/.setuptools-cmake-build/onnx/onnx-operators-ml.proto
    Generated: /home/curiouspan/studyingC/intel_test/onnx/.setuptools-cmake-build/onnx/onnx-data.proto
    -- Could NOT find pybind11 (missing: pybind11_DIR)
    -- pybind11 v2.10.4
    --
    -- ******** Summary ********
    --   CMake version                     : 3.22.1
    --   CMake command                     : /usr/bin/cmake
    --   System                            : Linux
    --   C++ compiler                      : /usr/bin/c++
    --   C++ compiler version              : 11.3.0
    --   CXX flags                         :  -Wnon-virtual-dtor
    --   Build type                        : Release
    --   Compile definitions               : __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
    --   CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH                 :
    --   CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX              : /usr/local
    --   CMAKE_MODULE_PATH                 :
    --
    --   ONNX version                      : 1.16.0
    --   ONNX NAMESPACE                    : onnx
    --   ONNX_USE_LITE_PROTO               : OFF
    --   USE_PROTOBUF_SHARED_LIBS          : OFF
    --   Protobuf_USE_STATIC_LIBS          : ON
    --   ONNX_DISABLE_EXCEPTIONS           : OFF
    --   ONNX_DISABLE_STATIC_REGISTRATION  : OFF
    --   ONNX_WERROR                       : OFF
    --   ONNX_BUILD_TESTS                  : OFF
    --   ONNX_BUILD_BENCHMARKS             : OFF
    --   ONNX_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS            :
    --   BUILD_SHARED_LIBS                 :
    --
    --   Protobuf compiler                 : /usr/bin/protoc
    --   Protobuf includes                 : /usr/include
    --   Protobuf libraries                : /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.a
    --   BUILD_ONNX_PYTHON                 : ON
    --     Python version                :
    --     Python executable             : /usr/bin/python3
    --     Python includes               : /usr/include/python3.10
    -- Configuring done
    -- Generating done
    -- Build files have been written to: /home/curiouspan/studyingC/intel_test/onnx/.setuptools-cmake-build
    [  2%] Built target gen_onnx_proto
    [  8%] Built target gen_onnx_operators_proto
    [  8%] Built target gen_onnx_data_proto
    Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target onnx_proto
    [ 22%] Built target onnx_proto
    Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target onnx
    [ 97%] Built target onnx
    Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target onnx_cpp2py_export
    [100%] Built target onnx_cpp2py_export
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
      File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
      File "/home/curiouspan/studyingC/intel_test/onnx/setup.py", line 321, in <module>
        setuptools.setup(
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        return run_commands(dist)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 163, in run_commands
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/home/curiouspan/studyingC/intel_test/onnx/setup.py", line 253, in run
        return super().run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/develop.py", line 34, in run
        self.install_for_development()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/develop.py", line 114, in install_for_development
        self.run_command('build_ext')
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/home/curiouspan/studyingC/intel_test/onnx/setup.py", line 259, in run
        return super().run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 79, in run
        _build_ext.run(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 339, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "/home/curiouspan/studyingC/intel_test/onnx/setup.py", line 288, in build_extensions
        if self.editable_mode:
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 103, in __getattr__
        raise AttributeError(attr)
    AttributeError: editable_mode
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error

    × python setup.py develop did not run successfully.
    │ exit code: 1
    ╰─> See above for output.

    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
    full command: /usr/bin/python3 -c '
    exec(compile('"'"''"'"''"'"'
    # This is <pip-setuptools-caller> -- a caller that pip uses to run setup.py
    #
    # - It imports setuptools before invoking setup.py, to enable projects that directly
    #   import from `distutils.core` to work with newer packaging standards.
    # - It provides a clear error message when setuptools is not installed.
    # - It sets `sys.argv[0]` to the underlying `setup.py`, when invoking `setup.py` so
    #   setuptools doesn'"'"'t think the script is `-c`. This avoids the following warning:
    #     manifest_maker: standard file '"'"'-c'"'"' not found".
    # - It generates a shim setup.py, for handling setup.cfg-only projects.
    import os, sys, tokenize

    try:
        import setuptools
    except ImportError as error:
        print(
            "ERROR: Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in "
            "the build environment.",
            file=sys.stderr,
        )
        sys.exit(1)

    __file__ = %r
    sys.argv[0] = __file__

    if os.path.exists(__file__):
        filename = __file__
        with tokenize.open(__file__) as f:
            setup_py_code = f.read()
    else:
        filename = "<auto-generated setuptools caller>"
        setup_py_code = "from setuptools import setup; setup()"

    exec(compile(setup_py_code, filename, "exec"))
    '"'"''"'"''"'"' % ('"'"'/home/curiouspan/studyingC/intel_test/onnx/setup.py'"'"',), "<pip-setuptools-caller>", "exec"))' develop --no-deps
    cwd: /home/curiouspan/studyingC/intel_test/onnx/
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py develop did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue was raised here https://github.com/onnx/onnx/issues/5716 and it was suggested to ensure the `setuptools` in the environment is up to date. You should also use `pip install -e .` for editable mode installs, and use `python -m build` for building wheels. If the error persists, you can visit the link to try the alternative solutions suggested.